# How to convert Oracle inline queries to snowflake

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help in understanding how to convert a sql inline query into Snowflake .As inline queries are not supported in Snowflake,

Sample Inline query :

```
SELECT   
    xsgq.name,
    (SELECT attribute3
     FROM employee
     WHERE employee_id = xsgq.employee_id) AS "planTitle",
    ROUND (xsgq.goal_value, 2) AS "goal"
FROM 
    employee_ext xsgq, region_ext Xcpe           
WHERE     
    xsgq.employee_id = 41825
    AND xsgq.fiscal_year IN (2021,2020,2019)
    AND Xcpe.region = 'USA'
GROUP BY              
    xsgq.employee_id,
ORDER BY 
    xsgq.start_date DESC
```

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Well, for this example it would suffice of course to simply inner join the employee table. A more general solution is an outer join.

Comment: For clarity, Snowflake does support inline queries. You may be thinking of subselects.

Comment: yes Greg , actually i was trying to convert a oracle cursor  .  which has multiple subselect queries.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite is as left join. Also join between `xsgq` and `Xcpe` is a cross join in ANSI style. You are not selecting any columns from `Xcpe`, check do you need it at all, or maybe you over-simplified your query. Anyway, inline  employee query can be rewritten as is a left join:

```
SELECT   
    xsgq.name,
    emp.attribute3 AS "planTitle",
    ROUND (xsgq.goal_value, 2) AS "goal"
FROM 
    employee_ext xsgq 
    cross join ( select * from region_ext Xcpe where Xcpe.region = 'USA') Xcpe 
    left join employee emp on emp.employee_id = xsgq.employee_id       
WHERE     
    xsgq.employee_id = 41825
    AND xsgq.fiscal_year IN (2021,2020,2019)
GROUP BY              
    xsgq.employee_id,
ORDER BY 
    xsgq.start_date DESC
```